# How to rebase commits of the same branch in Git?

Tags: git, git-interactive-rebase

I did some wrong rebasing and conflict resolution in Git, so I ended up in this stupid situation:

```
*   8379515 (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge branch 'binary-mobile'
|\
| * 21b247a (binary-mobile) Add Binary Mobile
| * c66dced Add Music Collection
* | cbbe364 Add task Music Collection
|/
* 8e9ccae Update README.md
* 31d2050 Reorganize repo and add README files
* 88fe4fd Rename readme file
* 8ed72bd Reorganize the structure of the repo
* 219a25a Update README.md
* 60921e6 Create README.md
* 1de4f36 Initial commit
```

My problem is that commits `Add task Music Collection` and `Add Music Collection` are the same. I want to:

- have my branch follow a single path;
- only have one commit with the title `Add Music Collection`.

Could I just do `git rebase -i 8e9ccae` and then squash `c66dced` into `cbbe364` and rename `cbbe364` to `Add Music Collection`? I think that the problem in the first place was that I had pushed the commits I wanted to rebase to Github, but I thought that as long as nobody else is working with them, this is ok?

Comment: Why don't you chesk git reflog and use git reset?

Comment: @klm123, could you give a few more details. I am learning git, so I am not sure what exactly to do? If I just checkout a previous state from the reflog, then what?

Comment: I gave more details in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

- go back to the point where the commits are ok
- create a branch there, and cherry-pick the commits you want
- git reset to the starting-point of the branch, this will become your new master/head, but you saved your inbetween commits
- merge branch and done! :)

So in code that would be something like:

```
git checkout 8e9ccae
git checkout -b better_changes
git cherry-pick c66dced
git cherry-pick 21b247a
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^6  //check correct nr of steps with git reflog
git merge better_changes
```

And then force push to origin :)

Comment: All three answers were good suggestions, but cherry-picking was the easiest for me. I tried what klm123 proposed, but when I `git reset` to a particular commit from the reflog I also see somethings I had done after that commit, so not exactly a snap shot in time. The problem is obviously in my git skills, but the cherry-picking solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following if I would be stuck with this problem:

1.) Rebase the commits between `cbbe364` (exclusive) and `21b247a` (inclusive) onto your `8e9ccae`.

```
git rebase --onto 8e9ccae cbbe364 21b247a
```

This moves the commits `c66dced` and `21b247a` directly onto `8e9ccae`. This will result in another hash value for the newest commit *Add Binary Mobile*, let's call the hash value 'commit2'
*(Tree may not be 100% accurate, have no git repository to reproduce it)*

```
*   8379515 (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) Merge branch 'binary-mobile'
|\
| * 21b247a (binary-mobile) Add Binary Mobile
| * c66dced Add Music Collection
| | cbbe364 Add task Music Collection
|/
|
|
| * commit2 (HEAD) Add Binary Mobile
| * commit1 Add Music Collection
|/
* 8e9ccae Update README.md
* 31d2050 Reorganize repo and add README files
* 88fe4fd Rename readme file
* 8ed72bd Reorganize the structure of the repo
* 219a25a Update README.md
* 60921e6 Create README.md
* 1de4f36 Initial commit
```

2.) After that move your `master` down (down the 'Tree') to `commit2`:

```
git branch -d master
git checkout commit2
git branch master

| * commit2 (HEAD, master) Add Binary Mobile
| * commit1 Add Music Collection
|/
* 8e9ccae Update README.md
```

3.) Now you have your `master` where it belongs, namely on `commit2`.
If you want to follow your branch on a 'single line', you need to get rid of `binary-mobile` branch, just delete it:

```
git branch -D binary-mobile
```

Because the commit `21b247a` now has no branch name, and you do not work on this branch (no HEAD) the branch will disappear.

4.) Finally push your changes (force is necessary in this case). This will move your `origin/master` down to `master`, and the merge branch *should* disappear.

```
git push master --force


* commit2 (HEAD, master, origin/master) Add Binary Mobile
* commit1 Add Music Collection
* 8e9ccae Update README.md
* 31d2050 Reorganize repo and add README files
* 88fe4fd Rename readme file
* 8ed72bd Reorganize the structure of the repo
* 219a25a Update README.md
* 60921e6 Create README.md
* 1de4f36 Initial commit
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you need to simply check and undo what you did wrong.

With `git reflog` ([See here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html)) you can check history of everything you made with your git repository. All these changes are stored in git, so you can go back to any state your repository had for previous 2 months.

With 
`git reset --hard HEAD@{NumberOfTheChange}` ([See here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html)) you can undo any changes in the repository. (But please be aware that this way you can't undo changes in the files, which was not tracked by git)

After this you can do what you want.